# Why does Convert To Single change the values at the End

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a Windows Form application to talk with a PLC.  I need to be able to pass Float values between the application and the PLC.  I am running into a problem when converting the int values to floats.

The value to send to PLC: 3334688901
The value after Single Convert: 3.334689E+09
If you convert that to a String you get: 3334689024

here is my code:
string sValue = "3334688901";
float OutputValue = Convert.ToSingle(sValue);

Is there a way to make the Convert.ToSingle convert the value correctly?

I have tried many things that did not work.

Comment: Are you crushing rocks into stones?  And then to powder?

Comment: Floating point values have a limited precision. Single can’t handle that many significant digits. Double could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision and a maximum of 9 digits internally.  The number you are converting has 10 digits.  Try Convert.ToDouble instead of Convert.ToSingle.

```
Double OutputValue = Convert.ToDouble("3334688901");
Console.WriteLine(OutputValue);
```

Comment: By the way, my uncle programs on a PLC, and his company crushes rock in huge rock quarry.  Using such large numbers led me to think you might be doing something that turns things into powder.

Comment: that makes sense, but the value must be a floating point value.  I am using a Custom DLL to communicate with the PLC and you must assign a Float to the variable.

Comment: If the consumer is only using float precision, then it doesn't matter if you send 3334688901 or send 3334689024 because the consumer can't distinguish between them.

Comment: I figured it out.  The custom DLL has a special property for assigning the value when it is large like that.  Thanks for your help

Comment: It appears that Microsoft documents 10 versions of .NET and .NET Core.  They are trying to transition everything to .NET Core to be compatible with "EVERYTHING".  Anyway, these types of issues are documented here.  Select the .NET version and the class (ie: System.Single in your case) of interest.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=net-7.0